# Get the name of the select with onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the name of the select when you select a option, for example:

If I select the 2 option in the select1 I need to catch the name of the select(in this case select1) via js or jquery, that's why I'm using "this" as a parameter in the onchange, the problem is that I dont know how to get the name of the select with this "this", I tried this.name but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Thx

```
<select onchange="jsFunction(this);" name="select1">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>

<select onchange="jsFunction(this);" name="select2">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>
```

EDIT:

The function has literally nothing:

```
jsFuntion(element){
alert(element.name);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the callback function itself it's impossible to give specific advice.

Comment: Typo: `jsFuntion` -> `jsFunction`

Comment: you need to declare jsFunction as a function: 'function jsFunction(element) {...code...}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to receive `this` as a parameter in the function, then get the `name` property from that element, like this:

```js
function jsFunction(el) {
  var name = el.name;
  console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="jsFunction(this);" name="select1">
  <option selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<select onchange="jsFunction(this);" name="select2">
  <option selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

However the `on*` event attributes are generally considered bad practice and should be avoided where possible. Instead you should be using unobtrusive event handlers in the JS code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var name = this.name;
    console.log(name);
  });
})
```

```html
<select name="select1">
  <option selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
  <option selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this snippet. It gives the name of select in console.

```js
function myfunction(Element)
    {
        console.log($(Element).prop("name"));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select onchange="myfunction(this)" name="select1">
        <option selected>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <select onchange="myfunction(this);" name="select2">
        <option selected>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Adding jQuery just for this seems a little overkill when you can just use `Element.name`

Answer (score 1):

In your `jsFunction` code, you can dereference the `name` property like this:

```js
function jsFunction(obj) {
console.log(obj.name);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="jsFunction(this);" name="select1">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>

<select onchange="jsFunction(this);" name="select2">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>
```

Passing `this.name` also works.

```js
function jsFunction(nm) {
console.log(nm);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="jsFunction(this.name);" name="select1">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>

<select onchange="jsFunction(this.name);" name="select2">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name thought your `jsFunction` try this.

As Pointy says you can also use obj.name

```js
function jsFunction(obj) {
  //console.log($(obj).attr("name"))
  console.log(obj.name)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="jsFunction(this);" name="select1">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>

<select onchange="jsFunction(this);" name="select2">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>
```

Comment: Or simply `obj.name`

Comment: @Pointy True true, totally forgot that, cheers